# Memory Issue - Java 8 + Tomcat 6 vs Java 8 + Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-management, memory-leaks, performance-testing

I upgraded softwares in my java application from Java 1.6.0_22,Tomcat 6.0.26 to Java 1.8.0_92, Tomcat 8.5.3. I see serious performance issues. I narrowed it down to tomcat. I run load test with Java 8+Tomcat 6 it is responsive, atleast 50 transactions/sec. But when I run the same test with Java 8+Tomcat 8 after few runs it is chocked up and tps goes down to 10 transactions/sec.

The one thing I notice is when I do 'top' in the linux server with Tomcat 6 %MEM never goes above 25%, but with Tomcat 8 it goes above %85 thats when I see low responsiveness, and it gets worse with every load test execution. Is there a way I can tune it to match Tomcat 6 performance. I don want production performance to be degraded because of the upgrade. Is there anything Im missing?
Below are the Visual VM , Top snapshots of Tomcat 6 & Tomcat 8.

Tomcat 6:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Tomcat 8:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add -Xincgc tomcat JAVA_OPTS to achieve desired performance. Though -Xincgc is deprecated in java 8, I had to use this for time being until I find a better solution.